# Audio playback halts/stops on Chrome 64

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

Google just changed how Chrome preloads `audio` and `video`; see: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/preload-metadata

It's my understanding that simply setting `preload` attribute to `auto` should fix the problem, however, I have been unable to do so:

- https://jsfiddle.net/NinoSkopac/f4zscrdy/1/

```js
let mp3 = 'https://s3-staging.read2me.online/audio/5a745d88483d86.76121223.mp3';
let audio = new Audio(mp3);
audio.preload = 'auto';

audio.play();
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/NinoSkopac/rst8aspm/

```html
<audio src="https://s3-staging.read2me.online/audio/5a745d88483d86.76121223.mp3" preload="auto" autoplay></audio>
```

Both of these will stop playing within a minute on Chrome 64 and Chrome 65-dev (other browsers and older Chromes are unaffected). I have replicated this issue on Mac, Windows and Android.

During my debug process, I have attached all [possible media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to the JS object (i.e. `audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => { console.log('timeupdate') })`) and at first the events were firing like this:

`progress
timeupdate
progress
timeupdate
[...]`

Later like this:

`timeupdate
timeupdate
timeupdate
[...]`

When the audio playback stopped, I got a handful of `error` events, and dumping `audio.error` returns: `PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: Failed to send audio packet for decoding: timestamp=81763265 duration=26122 size=201 side_data_size=0 is_key_frame=1 encrypted=0 discard_padding (ms)=(0, 0)`

How do I fix this? Is this a Chrome bug?

UPDATE:

- OGG plays fine: https://jsfiddle.net/NinoSkopac/2hktqcqt/1/
- This does seem to be a Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794782
- A similar error on Github: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/1529

UPDATE 2:

`chrome://media-internals/` reveals this:

[image]

UPDATE 3:

This issue has been fixed in Chrome 65.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a couple of days of trial and error and research, I have confirmed what doesn't and does work.

### Doesn't work

#### mp3wrap

`mp3wrap output.mp3 *.mp3`
the output file is still corrupted and halts

#### ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i "concat:0.mp3|1.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3`
the output file is still corrupted and halts

### Does work

#### mp3val with -f argument

Simply concatenate/implode your audio binaries (in PHP I do `implode('', $audioBinaries)` and then run `mp3val -f concatenated-audio-file.mp3`. The `-f` argument is essential and it means "try to fix errors".

**How to install mp3val?**

On MacOS: `brew install mp3val`
On Deb/Ubu: `apt-get install mp3val`

Comment: When you say 'concatenate' your audio files you mean that mp3 files must be merged into one single mp3? Or this is done to each mp3 file? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @Cruclax No, they don't have to be merged, but the problem in my case happened because i was manually concatenating/merging multiple mp3 files without regard to headers, and that's why Chrome 64 couldn't play them.

Comment: mp3val -f didn't found/fix any errors on my files, but reencoding them using lame did solve it.

Comment: @Cruclax yes I imagine it would've, but the beauty of mp3val is that it doesn't reencode the files, and therefore there is no quality loss. Weird that it didn't though

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I am facing with concatenating technique. With ffmpeg, it works fine. Try ffmpeg with this command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i "{textfile}" -c:v copy -ab 48k -y "{output}"
```

**textfile** will have a list of files written per line.