# HTML5 audio stopping automatically before reaching its duration in Chrome

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have an Angular 2 project in production for a while and I've been informed that lately some functions are not working properly in Chrome. Safari works fine.

After some investigation I realized that the problem is that audio elements "ended" events are not being fired. 
I'm printing the currentTime / Duration and all of them automatically stop short at a random percentage of completion.
e.g.

[image]

I'm completely lost on what might be suddenly causing this. Any ideas?

```
        let el = <HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById(id);

        this.audio.src = <string>(<HTMLSourceElement>el.children[0].getAttribute("src"));
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();


        this.audio.onended = function() {
            ...// THIS NEVER RUNS
        }
        this.audio.ontimeupdate = function() {
            console.log(this.currentTime, this.duration);

            ...// THIS DOES BUT currentTime never reaches duration
        }
```

UPDATE:
I was testing with Chrome latest version 64.0.3282.140 at the moment and when I downgraded to version 63 the problem went away...

Comment: Can't say without some code.

Comment: @Phix edited the question and added code

Comment: What audio format is this? It has been an issue in chrome for a long time (years). I suspect it has to do with pre-estimating duration with some formats and forgetting to throw the event if actual duration is less. A workaround could be to use setTimeout but this will not work so elegantly if user can pause the audio at some point (you have to cancel the timeout, calculate the reminder from current position and so forth). Any workaround incl detecting when an event is no longer broadcasting will likely have a hackish feel to it though.

Comment: @K3N interesting, I will investigate on that. However (see edit) this was working properly for almost a year now and it started to malfunction with google latest update: 64.0.3282.140. I see they included some changes related to audio and video (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history)

Comment: @K3N format is mp3... Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo

Comment: There is a similar issue here: [audio-playback-halts-stops-on-chrome-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584075/audio-playback-halts-stops-on-chrome-64) - it seems it can be resolved by re-econding your mp3 files. Anyway, it's a Chrome bug, since in older versions and different browsers everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in a Chrome update that makes its audio player behave this way when reproducing "damaged" mp3 files.

It is discussed more in depth [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794782) and on this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584075/audio-playback-halts-stops-on-chrome-64).

Recommended ways to fix the files are:

- mp3val -f (didn't work for me)
- Reencode with lame command (did work for me)

According to the chromium bug thread it will be fixed in version 66.

Comment: Your second suggestion worked for me as well. First encoded with ```ffmpeg -i something.wav something.mp3``` and it didn't reach duration, but with ```lame something.wav something.mp3``` it did.