# Custom javascript Video player stops after 11 seconds

Tags: javascript, video-player

I am currently developing a custom javascript videoplayer for my website to be able to show some showreels. It works perfectly fine in firefox but in chrome the demo video stops everytime after 11 seconds but the buffering process has already loaded more than 11s.

Here is the link to the videoplayer: https://www.cankarka.com/en/portfolio

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I got no errors in the console.

Thanks in advance :)

This is my HTML:

```
            <div class="custom-video-player">
                <video class="video" src="inc/video.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
                <div class="video-controls">
                    <div class="video-bar">
                        <div id="currentBuffer" class="currentBuffer"></div>
                        <div id="currentProcess" class="currentProcess"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="skip-back" class="skipBack" type="button"></button>
                        <button id="playPause" type="button"></button>
                        <button id="skip-front" class="skipForward" type="button"></button>
                        <button id="volumeBtn" class="volumeHigh" type="button"></button>

                        <div class="volume-slider-container">
                            <div class="volume-slider-container-inner">
                                <div id="volume-slider" class="volume-slider"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="volume-slider-range"></div>

                        <div class="videoTimer-container">
                            <span id="videoCurrentTime" class="videoTimer"></span> <span id="slash" class="videoTimer">/</span> <span id="videoTime" class="videoTimer"></span>
                        </div>

                        <button id="fullscreenToggle" class="fullscreen" type="button"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
function initializeVideoPlayer()
{
var videoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-video-player');
for (var i = 0; i < videoPlayers.length; ++i)
    {
    initControls(videoPlayers[i]);
    }
}

function initControls(videoPlayerContainer)
{
var video = videoPlayerContainer.querySelector('.video');
var videoBarContainer = videoPlayerContainer.querySelector('.video-bar');
video.onerror = function()
    {
    console.log("Error: " + video.error.code);
    };

// Timelines
var currentProcess = videoPlayerContainer.querySelector("div.currentProcess");
var currentBuffer = videoPlayerContainer.querySelector("div.currentBuffer");

// Buttons
var playPauseBtn = videoPlayerContainer.querySelector('#playPause');

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateTimeline);
video.addEventListener('click', togglePlayPause);
video.addEventListener('progress', updateBuffer);
playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlayPause);
skipBackward.addEventListener('click', skipBackwardFunction);
skipForward.addEventListener('click', skipForwardFunction);
volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', setVolumeByBtn);

let mouseDown = false;
videoBarContainer.addEventListener('click', scrub);
videoBarContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mouseDown && scrub(e));
videoBarContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseDown = true);
videoBarContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseDown = false);

function scrub(e)
    {
    var scrubTime = (e.offsetX / videoBarContainer.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
    video.currentTime = scrubTime;
    }

function skipForwardFunction()
    {
    video.currentTime += skipTime;
    }

function skipBackwardFunction()
    {
    video.currentTime -= skipTime;
    }

function updateBuffer()
    {
    var duration = video.duration;
    if (duration > 0)
        {
        for (var i = 0; i < video.buffered.length; ++i)
            {
            if (video.buffered.start(video.buffered.length - 1 - i) < video.currentTime)
                {
                currentBuffer.style.width = (video.buffered.end(video.buffered.length - 1 - i) / duration) * 100 + "%";
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

function updateTimeline()
    {
    // Timeline updaten
    var percent = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
    currentProcess.style.width = percent + "%";

    // Aktuelle Zeit anzeigen
    var min = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 60);
    var sec = Math.floor(video.currentTime - min * 60);

    if (sec < 10)
        {
        sec = "0" + sec;
        }
    if (min < 10)
        {
        min = "0" + min;
        }
    if (min >= 60 && min < 120)
        {
        min = "01:" + (min - 60);
        }
    else if (min >= 120 && min < 180)
        {
        min = "02:" + (min - 120);
        }
    else if (min >= 180 && min < 240)
        {
        min = "03:" + (min - 180);
        }
    else if (min >= 240 && min < 300)
        {
        min = "04:" + (min - 240);
        }
    else if (min >= 300 && min < 360)
        {
        min = "05:" + (min - 300);
        }
    else
        {
        min = "00:" + min;
        }

    // Gesamte Zeit berechnen
    var minTotal = Math.floor(video.duration / 60);
    var secTotal = Math.floor(video.duration - minTotal * 60);
        
    if (secTotal < 10)
        {
        secTotal = "0" + secTotal;
        }
    if (minTotal < 10)
        {
        minTotal = "0" + minTotal;
        }
    if (minTotal >= 60 && minTotal < 120)
        {
        minTotal = "01:" + (minTotal - 60);
        }
    else if (minTotal >= 120 && minTotal < 180)
        {
        minTotal = "02:" + (minTotal - 120);
        }
    else if (minTotal >= 180 && minTotal < 240)
        {
        minTotal = "03:" + (minTotal - 180);
        }
    else if (minTotal >= 240 && minTotal < 300)
        {
        minTotal = "04:" + (minTotal - 240);
        }
    else if (minTotal >= 300 && minTotal < 360)
        {
        minTotal = "05:" + (minTotal - 300);
        }
    else
        {
        minTotal = "00:" + minTotal;
        }
        
    videoCurrentTime.innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
    videoTime.innerHTML = minTotal + ":" + secTotal;

    if (video.ended)
        {
        playPauseBtn.className = "play";
        }
    }

function togglePlayPause()
    {
    if (video.paused)
        {
        playVideo();
        }
    else
        {
        playPauseBtn.className = "play";
        video.pause();
        }
    }

function playVideo()
    {
    var playPromise = video.play();
    if (playPromise !== undefined)
        {
        playPromise.then(_ => {
            // Video started successfully
            playPauseBtn.className = "pause";
        }).catch(error => {
            // Video was interrupted
            playPauseBtn.className = "play";
        });
        }
    }
}

window.onload = initializeVideoPlayer;
```

Comment: can't help without seeing code

Comment: sorry, added the code :)

Comment: You can help to find the problem by reducing your code to a [mcve]. You don't need most of the functions. The volume control probably is unrelated to the problem

Comment: When the video is playing, an `error` event occurs, then a `timeupdate` event and finally a  `pause` event. They always occur at the same position. I suspect a file corruption (on the server or during HTTP transfer) but I cannot debug further because the error is of type `Event`, not `MediaError` as it should be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks for your reply! I modified the code to a more minimal example code

Comment: @GuerricP Thanks for your reply! I added a the code for that to the server and I got a ErrorCode 3 when the error occurrs. Here is the table of the error codes I found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError/code#Media_error_code_constants. But are they also being used by Chrome?

Comment: Yes they're the same in Chrome, that's what I thought, a decoding error

Comment: ok nice, how would I fix a decoding error? should I rerender the video? or is there a possibility to fix it in code?

Comment: No that means that the video is corrupted, try saving it to another format

Comment: I'll add an answer for future readers, can you tell me how you got a `MediaError` instead of `Event`?

Comment: I just followed this example code provided by Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError/code#Example

Comment: I also added the error callback code to my first code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to debug the video, you can use this code:

```
const videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

const b = HTMLMediaElement.prototype;

const allNames = new Set();
for (let o = b; o != Object.prototype; o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o)) {
  for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
    allNames.add(name);
  }
}

const array = Array.from(allNames).filter(x => /^on/.test(x)).map(x => x.substring(2));

array.forEach(x => videoElement.addEventListener(x, console.log));
```

This shows that an Event of type `error` occurs, followed by `timeupdate` and then `pause`.

To get the actual error, use `videoElement.error` which shows the following:

```
{
    code: 3,
    message: "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: Failed to send audio packet for decoding: {timestamp=12176542 duration=21250 size=516 is_key_frame=1 encrypted=0}"
}
```

That means your file is corrupted, try to encode it in a different way. Also, maybe this answer will help: [Audio playback halts/stops on Chrome 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584075/audio-playback-halts-stops-on-chrome-64)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! Re-Encoding the video file seemed to help, the video plays now normally in chrome and firefox! :-)